# Painting erasing when background colour is changed (by button)

Tags: java, colors, background

[Backgrounds1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yiVP4.png)
[backgrounds2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r0xgn.png)

how do i make it so that it stops erasing the picture when the background colour changes I tried tons of different ways like

1. setting a image as the background
2. drawing an giant oval over the background(it covers all the other stuff to ~*.*~)
3. putting it an layered pane like the background colour and trying all the different panes (it also covers everything)
   I thought about trying making it a button but when you colour over it the paint goes under the buttons like a second later so that wouldn't work...

```js
    if(f.getSource()==backgrounds) {
            getContentPane().setBackground(paints);
                    renbew = 7;
                    screen = 1;
                    clear = 1;
        }
```

ignore the three numbers they are for something else and don't have anything to do with the background colour changes.... and this is the thing that actually puts out the paint

```js
public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent f){ 
                 renbew = 7;
                 clear = 0;
        Graphics g = getGraphics();
               if(rainbows == 7){
            int R = (int)(Math.random()*256);
            int G = (int)(Math.random()*256);
            int B= (int)(Math.random()*256);
            Color mystery = new Color(R, G, B);
            Random random = new Random();
            final float hue = random.nextFloat();
            final float saturation = 1.0f;
            final float luminance = 1.0f; 
            mystery = Color.getHSBColor(hue, saturation, luminance);
            g.setColor(mystery);
            paints = mystery;
        g.fillOval(f.getX(), f.getY(), 8, 20);
        System.out.println("paintttyS in rainbows:D");
        if(rainbowsize == 1) {
            g.fillOval(f.getX(), f.getY(), 1, 2);
            System.out.println("painttys rainbow is small O.o");
        }else if(rainbowsize == 2) {
            g.fillOval(f.getX(), f.getY(), 8, 20);
            System.out.println("paintttyS in rainbows:D");
        }else if (rainbowsize == 3) {
            g.fillOval(f.getX(), f.getY(), 20, 20);
            System.out.println("SO BIG rainbows aaaaaaa");
        }else if (rainbowsize == 4) {
            g.fillOval(f.getX(), f.getY(), 40, 20);
            System.out.println("BIGGEST RAINBOW O.o");}
               }else if(colbalts == 2) {
                   Random randomGenerator = new Random();
                    int blue = randomGenerator.nextInt(256);
                    Color colbaltx = new Color(blue);
                    g.setColor(colbaltx);
                    paints = colbaltx;
                    g.fillOval(f.getX(), f.getY(), 8, 20);
                    System.out.println("paintttyS in deepest blues O.o");
                    if(colbaltsize == 1) {
                        g.fillOval(f.getX(), f.getY(), 1, 2);
                        System.out.println("painttys deepblue is small O.o");
                    }else if(colbaltsize == 2) {
                        g.fillOval(f.getX(), f.getY(), 8, 20);
                        System.out.println("paintttyS in deepest blues O.o");
                    }else if (colbaltsize == 3) {
                        g.fillOval(f.getX(), f.getY(), 20, 20);
                        System.out.println("SO BIG BLUE aaaaaaa");
                    }else if (colbaltsize == 4) {
                        g.fillOval(f.getX(), f.getY(), 40, 20);
                        System.out.println("BIGGEST BLUES!!!!! >.<");}}    
            else if (merdium.isEnabled()) {
            System.out.println("paintttyS:D");
            g.setColor(paints);
            g.fillOval(f.getX(), f.getY(), 8, 20);
        }else {
            if (smally.isEnabled()) {
            System.out.println("paintty is small O.o");
            g.setColor(paints);
            g.fillOval(f.getX(), f.getY(), 4, 10);
         }else {
            if (sizeme.isEnabled()) {
            System.out.println("SO BIG aaaaaaa");
            g.setColor(paints);
            g.fillOval(f.getX(), f.getY(), 20, 20);
         }else {
            if (sobig.isEnabled()) {
                System.out.println("teh BIGGESTBOY");
                g.setColor(paints);
                g.fillOval(f.getX(), f.getY(), 40, 20);
            }
         }
       }
     }
}
```

no matter what I do if the background changes for some reason it erasers the drawing and there isn't anything in the background button that should do anything to eraser it....

Comment: Don't use the getGraphics() method to do custom painting. Check out [Custom Painting Approaches](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/05/08/custom-painting-approaches/)

Comment: See also https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/.